# Group by an array of objects and select based on multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq, select, group-by

I have an array of objects that may contain duplicate records based on some ID.

I am trying to group the objects by ID and from each group pick the record where either status is 3 or with the earliest date (status takes precedence).

```
ID     Status  Last     LastModified             
1      1       Smith    02/06/2023 04:00 AM   
1      2       Smith    02/06/2023 02:00 AM   
2      1       Jones    02/01/2023 11:24 AM        
3      1       Jack     02/05/2023 02:00 AM   
3      3       Jack     02/06/2023 06:00 AM
```

What I would want from a query is to get the following:

```
ID     Status  Last     LastModified             
1      2       Smith    02/06/2023 02:00 AM   
2      1       Jones    02/01/2023 11:24 AM        
3      3       Jack     02/06/2023 06:00 AM
```

I get the records based on date but not sure how to stick the status portion in there:

```
var filtered = from d in tests.AsEnumerable()
                 group d by d.ID into g
                 select g.OrderBy(p => p.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

This returns:

```
ID     Status  Last     LastModified             
1      2       Smith    02/06/2023 02:00 AM   
2      1       Jones    02/01/2023 11:24 AM        
3      1       Jack     02/05/2023 02:00 AM
```

Comment: How about: `... select g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Status == 3).ThenBy(p => p.DateTime).FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: @TN Thanks, can you change your comment to an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var filtered =
    from d in tests.AsEnumerable()
    group d by d.ID into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Status == 3).ThenBy(p => p.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
```